# xCode extream long list of exception and can't debug view

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, view, nslayoutconstraint

Question: Is this a known bug?? and any work a round possible ?

(edit: xcode is 9.3, but I am getting this behavior since moving to xcode 9)

I ma having a serous problem with xCode 9 and using the debug consol to try and find the faulty view.

back in xcode 8 I did not have problems using the debug consol to color a view and see where it was. 
since xcode 9 I just get a really hard time getting any thing done using the debug consol.

this is what I get from using the "Debug view hierarchy" button

```
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x6000003222e0 (object 0x6000012464e0, a NSException)
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x10b86b2f8 sp=0x7ffeeb5d0420] for exception 0x6000003222c0
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x12615fd7b sp=0x7ffeeb5d05d0] for exception 0x6000003222c0
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(NSException)
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x10b86b2f8 sp=0x7ffeeb5d0420] for exception 0x6000003222c0

..... 100's of more line of this ......

objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x60800013d680 (object 0x608000e4fea0, a NSException)
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x108998e6b sp=0x7ffeeb5cffe0] for exception 0x60800013d660
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x12615fd7b sp=0x7ffeeb5d05d0] for exception 0x60800013d660
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(NSException)
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x108998e6b sp=0x7ffeeb5cffe0] for exception 0x60800013d660
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x12615fd7b sp=0x7ffeeb5d05d0] for exception 0x60800013d660
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x60800013d660 at 0x1261603b2
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
objc[13465]: EXCEPTIONS: releasing completed exception 0x60800013d680 (object 0x608000e4fea0, a NSException)
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- unsafeBitCast(0x7fd67ad94640, to: UIImageView.self).image = nil
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fd67ad94640).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

And as can be seen when I try to access any thing I just get this "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

The only time I get this to work is to reeboot the system. then any subsequent run I hit this problem. this is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Did you add any breakpoints ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Xcode or updating it to a latest Version 9.3.